# ruby - tab from row not respected

Tags: ruby, file, io

I'm reading a simple txt file very well. However i'm getting the data row with tab not respected.

Below the row in the file.

```
Anderson Silva    R$10 off R$20 of food    10.0    2          987         Fake St          Batman Inc
```

And below is the out line at pry.

As we can see the 987 and Fake St is together in the same row.

```
Anderson Silva
R$10 off R$20 of food
10.0
2
      987         Fake St
      Batman Inc
```

and here the simple code

```
line.split("\t").map do |col|
  col = col.split("\t")
  puts col
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your posted code: `line.split("\t")` splits line on any tabs it includes, and returns an array of the parts between the tabs. When you then map over that array, the individual elements can't possibly have any tabs left in them, so what is `col = col.split("\t")` supposed to accomplish? It's effectively the same as `col = [col]`.

Comment: Also `puts` returns `nil`, and it's the last expression in the `map` block. So,  the return value of the `map` method in this case will be an array full of `nil`s (like, `[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`). Of course, you're not doing anything with the return value anyway, so it doesn't really matter, but in that case, you'd be better off using `each` as @orde does.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly, but I'd suspect that there's not actually a tab where you expect one.

```
def contrived_method(str)
  str.split("\t").each do |col|
    col = col.split("\t")
    puts col
  end
end

line1 = "10.0\t2\t987         Fake St"
line2 = "10.0\t2\t987\tFake St"

contrived_method(line1)
#=> 10.0
#=> 2
#=> 987         Fake St

contrived_method(line2)
#=> 10.0
#=> 2
#=> 987
#=> Fake St
```

For demonstration, I've reduced the size of your string to show that the `String::split` method will indeed split on the supplied delimiter.  And--in this case--I've used `each`instead of `map`because there's no assignment.

You'll find the `inspect` method valuable in this case:

```
line1 = "10.0\t2\t987         Fake St"

puts line1.inspect
#=> "10.0\t2\t987         Fake St"
puts line1
#=> 10.0    2       987         Fake St
```